# Symfony2 add role after registration to user account using event_subscriber and FOSUser bundle

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

Working on my first large Symfony2 project and I'm having a little trouble grasping what's going on with event listener/subscribers.

I want to have an event subscriber that adds a role (BLOG_USER) to a FOSUser entity after the user registers their account.

Here's what I've got so far:

Registration listener:

```
namespace MyBlog\SiteBundle\EventListener;

use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class RegistrationListener implements EventSubscriberInterface {
    public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
        return array(
            FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS => 'onRegistrationSuccess',
        );
    }
    public function onRegistrationSuccess(FormEvent $event){
        $rolesArr = array('ROLE_USER', 'BLOG_USER');

        $user = $event->getForm()->getData();
        $user->setRoles($rolesArr);
    }
}
```

services.yml:

```
services:
    myblog_user.registration_listener:
        class: MyBlog\SiteBundle\EventListener\RegistrationListener
        arguments: []
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

security.yml:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/blog/, role: BLOG_USER }
```

So far when I register a new user, they can't access the /blog route (which is a set of CRUD screens) - I get an "access denied" message that would be expected for a user without the BLOG_USER role.

## EDIT:

My code does appear to add the role to the user in the database. In the fos_user table under roles my user has this:

```
a:1:{i:0;s:9:"BLOG_USER";}
```

It seems like my access_control doesn't see this however.

```
 {% if is_granted('BLOG_USER') %}
```

is_granted also fails - it can't see the roles the user has...

Comment: Does you set a [role hierarchy](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#hierarchical-roles) ? Such as `ROLE_BLOG_USER: ROLE_USER`

Comment: Yeah, I've got `BLOG_USER: ROLE_USER` - does it need to be `ROLE*` named?

Comment: Not sure, its more like a convention

Comment: Changed `BLOG_USER: ROLE_USER` to `ROLE_BLOG_USER: ROLE_USER` and changed the database role entry to `a:1:{i:0;s:14:"ROLE_BLOG_USER";}` and now the access control lists work (when updated to the new ROLE* name). Brilliant! - didn't even think the role naming/hierarchy could be the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was explained in the comments, problem was in role name. Roles must start with `ROLE_`.
So solution is to set role hierarchy lite that

```
ROLE_BLOG_USER: ROLE_USER
```

Quote from [documetation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#roles)

> All roles must begin with the ROLE_ prefix to be managed by Symfony2.
>   If you define your own roles with a dedicated Role class (more
>   advanced), don't use the ROLE_ prefix.